# Vungle 3.0.10 for iOS handling ad not available

Tags: ios, vungle-ads

I'm integrating Vungle into my next app, and I've been able to get everything to work properly, but the one thing that I cannot find in the [documentation](https://github.com/Vungle/vungle-resources/blob/master/iOS-resources/iOS-advanced-settings.md) is a delegate method for handling an ad *not* loading.

There doesn't seem to be a `adNotServed:` or `adNotAvailable:` method.

Will this never happen? What if the user attempts to play the ad, but they don't have internet. How do I handle this?

---

#### Edit:

If I launch my app with no internet, Vungle is never started, so when I go to play the ad, nothing happens. There are no error messages; nothing is logged...

Answer (score 1):

There are no such methods available in Vungle SDK. but you can use `(BOOL)isAdPlayable;` to check if an Ad is available (cached) before displaying it.

EXTRA: Also Vungle SDK has a delegate method `- (void)vungleSDKAdPlayableChanged:(BOOL)isAdPlayable;` Implement it and Vungle SDK will inform you when it has finished cacheing (when Ad is available to display).